# DataGridView Sort throws exception: Control must be bound to IBindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sorting, datagridview

I'm using Entity Framework (EF), and have a `BindingList` I can get from the context (using the [DbExtensions.ToBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696575%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method), and I have a form with a `DataGridView`.

The objective is to display the contents of the EF table on the `DataGridView`, so I have the following code *in the form's constructor* to set the `DataGridView`'s `DataSource` to a `BindingSource` and that `BindingSource`'s `DataSource` to the `BindingList` from EF:

```
categoryBindSrc.DataSource = _context.Categories.Local.ToBindingList();
categoryDataGrid.Sort(categoryDataGrid.Columns["categorySortIdColumn"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Before that, in the Form's generated code, these lines exist:

```
categoryDataGrid.DataSource = categoryBindSrc;
categorySortIdColumn.DataPropertyName = "SortId";
```

This code is in the form's constructor, but when I run it, I get the following exception (I truncated the stack trace):

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233079
Message=DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted.
Source=System.Windows.Forms
StackTrace:
    at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SortDataBoundDataGridView_PerformCheck(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn)
    at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SortInternal(IComparer comparer, DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, ListSortDirection direction)
    at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.Sort(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, ListSortDirection direction)
```

To my understanding, `BindingList` does implement `IBindingList` so that shouldn't be the problem. The [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0868ft3z.aspx) method says the `DataGridView` must be data-bound (it is) and that the sort-by-column's `DataPropertyName` property is set (it is) *which causes the column's `IsDataBound` property to return true (when debugging it shows false in the watch window)*

It seems that the problem is that `IsDataBound` isn't getting updated, but I don't know what `SortDataBoundDataGridView_PerformCheck` (the method that threw the exception) checks for exactly, or why `IsDataBound` wouldn't be set.

I tried to provide all the code you need to understand the question, but let me know if you need more.  I also checked several related questions on S/O--none of the answers helped.

**EDIT:** It appears I can call Sort just fine from any other method except the constructor. This might be a threading issue.

Comment: Try setting the datagridview datasource directly to the IBindingList.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I was using a `BindingSource` to communicate with the `BindingNavigator` though, but I'll play around with it and see if I can get around.

Comment: Edited to point out Sort was called in the form's constructor, but could be called from anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the line `categoryBindSrc.DataSource = _context.Categories.Local.ToBindingList();` must be calling another thread that hasn't finished when Sort is called, so a couple of properties that are checked by `SortDataBoundDataGridView_PerformCheck` haven't been updated yet.

Therefore, the solution is to call the method after that thread has finished.  A nice place to put it so it still achieves its affect of sorting the data members before the users sees them is by overriding the form's OnLoad method and calling Sort there.